# Add qtranslate language select box to menu

Tags: menus, plugin-qtranslate

I can't find any info on how to operate qtranslate and add the select box to change language to the right of my header navigation.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you read the [plugin's FAQ](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3&p=16#p16), you'll find your answer...

Comment: if want to add your comment as an answer, I will approve it. Thank you

Comment: I don't think RTFM is a good answer :o) - maybe you can post the code itself and mark it as the correct answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my header.php I added the following

```
<div style="float: right; margin: 7px 15px 0 0;">
    <?=qtrans_generateLanguageSelectCode('dropdown');?>
</div>
```

`<?=..?>` is the same as `<?php echo ... ?>` or  `<?php function(); ?>`, but I prefer the shortcode

just next to: `<?php ct_primary_nav_menu(); ?>`